# Correct way to await in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-webflux

We have a HTTP endpoint that takes a command and send it via kafka to another place, then we **MUST** wait the response via kafka and then return ResponseEntity to client.

```
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> post(@RequestBody Mono<byte[]> b) {
    return b.flatMap(
            identifyType -> service.requestProcess(identifyType).flatMap(this::toResponse));
  }
```

In the service:

```
public Mono<String> requestProcess(byte[] b) {
    String r = authenticationService.waitForAuthentication(parseBytes(b));
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(r)) {
      throw new CustomException("Failed to authenticate");
    }
    return Mono.just(r);
}
```

In the authenticationService

```
public String waitForAuthentication(String data) {
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Listener listener = new Listener(countDownLatch);
    //another setup
    subscribe("topic_abc", String.class, listener);
    sendAuthenticationRequestToKafka(data);
    try {
      boolean b = countDownLatch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      if(b) return listerner.getData();
      else throw new CustomExcetion();
    catch(Exception e) {
      throw new CustomExcetion();
    }
}
```

The listener

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Listener implements Consumer<String> {
  @Getter private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch;
  @Getter private String data;

  @Override
  public void accept(String data) {
    this.data = data;
    // count to 0 
    countDownLatch.countDown();
  }
}
```

I read document and all of them say that we should never sleep/block/await on webflux application because it will block the current thread and the thread cannot handle another HTTP request.

But in our case, await is a must. We cannot change the flow above because client is a blackbox. Please suggest a correct way to await in webflux application/controller. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen a really clean way to get asynchronous-but-non-reactive data into the reactive stream. Your use of countdown latch is as good as any.

However, if you use the [ReactiveKafka](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/) library, then you won't have to do any of the clumsy blocking.

#### UPDATE

I actually did find a relatively elegant solution that uses [MonoSink](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html).

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> post(@RequestBody Mono<byte[]> b) {
    return b.map(String::new)
        .flatMap(data -> Mono.<String>create(sink -> {
          Consumer<String> kafkaListener = sink::success;

          subscribe("topic_abc", String.class, kafkaListener);
          sendAuthenticationRequestToKafka(data);
        })
        .map(this::toResponse);
}
```

This assumes that `subscribe`, and `sendAuthenticationRequestToKafka` are in scope. If you move that to the service layer, you can have that method return `Mono<String>`.

Also, I don't know how Kafka handles errors, but you could create error handlers that forward those to the sink.